# SQL - Insert 25000 rows at once

Tags: sql, database, scripting, phpmyadmin

I need to create a table that has 25000 auto incremented rows, and 4 columns in all, with null values in them(except for AI ID number). Any idea how to do that? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Option #1) Do the thing you do to add 1 row 25,000 times, Option #2) depends on the database/environment your using, You need to edit the question to show this.

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin ...

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to achieve your requirement?

Comment: Please specify the database backend. The code to do this may be vendor specific.

Comment: No, I'm asking what I need to do, to do this. I've tried to add manually, but 25000 is beyond stupid to do by hand, there is an easy way, a script or something like that.

Comment: I don't know what backend. How do I find that out? It's an SQL database in phpMyAdmin, that's all I know.

Comment: Firstly i would point you towards this question, in case you need random data at some point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608438  But since you need nulls, have a look at my answer

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Gives an error about MariaDB, which this lovely system does not allow me to paste here for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below simple while loop to populate your table with non-random data (null in your case) in Sql Server:

```
declare @counter int = 0

while @counter < 25000
begin
  insert <yourtablenamehere> (column1, column1, column1, column1)
  values (null, null, null, null)

  select @counter = @counter+1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out, apparently I have to use a special MariaDB syntax. Anyway, this did the trick:

```
    DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS createType1Table$$

CREATE PROCEDURE createType1Table()
BEGIN
 DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
 WHILE count < 25000 DO
 SET count = count + 1;
   INSERT INTO type1Cards (ID, CardTypeID, CardID, GroupID)
   VALUES (count, 1, count , 0);

 END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

then

```
CALL createType1Table();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '"&firstName&"','" &lastName&"','" &dob&'",'" &gender&'","' &joinDate& "','" &sport_code&"','" &sport_name&"' from dual union all";
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).